# rails devise change email verification by other field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've created an new rails API.
It will work only on mobile so it will need a `phone` number to create an account.

But now Devise is always requesting an `email`, how can I tell devise that I want him to focus on my field `phone` ?

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email can't be blank):
```

I want it to change to

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Phone can't be blank):
```

and do every basic devise verification with the phone number

Comment: do you want to use phone filed as login key?

Comment: register with phone and password only

Answer (score 0):

You should tell devise that the authentication_key is the `phone` field and not the `email` field

Modify `config/initializers/devise.rb` to have:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :phone ]
```

Comment: It's only for authentication right ? not registration?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. But the only time I played with authentication_keys, I completely replaced the email with a username, and users were not allowed to register (accounts were created by an admin). So your mileage may vary....